# Как заменить контент html-тега, только если контент совпадает с "0"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть код html

```
<span class="span_prise">0<span> грн</span></span>
<span class="span_prise">129<span> грн</span></span>
<span class="span_prise">203<span> грн</span></span>
```

Как на стороне клиента заменить содержимое всех span, у которых контент 0 (нулевая цена)? (в данном примере - только у первого элемента). Или сделать его невидимым, или выбрать при помощи CSS/js/jquery.

Comment: заменить на что?

Comment: На "Цену уточняйте". Но это неважно, на любые символы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".span_prise").each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  if (parseFloat($this.text().replace(",", ".")) === 0) {
    $this.replaceWith("<strong>Бесплатно!</strong>")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="span_prise">0<span> грн</span></span>
<span class="span_prise">129<span> грн</span></span>
<span class="span_prise">203<span> грн</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Команду `price[i].style.background = 'red';` замените на нужную вам, т.к. не понятно, что вы хотите с этой строкой сделать. Чтобы сделать невидимой, например, пропишите `price[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';`

```js
var price = document.querySelectorAll('.span_prise');
for ( var i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
  if ( price[i].innerHTML == "0<span> грн</span>" ) {
    price[i].style.background = 'red';
  }
};
```

```html
<span class="span_prise">0<span> грн</span></span>
<span class="span_prise">129<span> грн</span></span>
<span class="span_prise">203<span> грн</span></span>
```